# Am I using "spend a day" correctly here?

Tags: grammaticality, writing-style

Is this a correct usage?

> How do you spend a typical day at
>   school?

What are the alternatives?

Comment: Please specify what your *specific* problem with the sentence is. (The article? The adjective? Something else? Why do you think it's problematic? What are the alternatives *you* have in mind?) General proofreading requests are [off-topic](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: I am not sure that is "spend a day" a correct usage, so I asked this question.

Comment: Yours is right, though I'd phrase it differently as *"What's a typical day at school like?"*

Answer (score 2):

Your example sentence *How do you spend a typical day at school?* is perfectly correct. In particular, the idiom *to spend a day* is correct. Furthermore, you are allowed to modify the word *day* with an adjective or other modifier without harming the sense of the idiom (which isn't true for all idiomatic constructions). So your use of *a typical day* is completely correct and expresses what you are trying to ask very well.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using "how", then it is "**how do you [insert verb]**". 
Eg. "**How do you spend** a typical day at school?" is correct.

If you're using "what", then it is "**what is**". 
Eg. "**What is** a typical day at school for you?"